# How to apply check on loop using Eloquent ORM using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, relationship, isset

My controller code:

```
            public function getAllUsers()
{
    $data=array();
    $users = User::with('roles','userBasicInfo','userFacility')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user){
        $name="";
        $doctor="";
        if (isset($user->roles)){
            foreach ($user->roles as $role){
                $name .=$role['name'].',';
        }
    }

            if (isset($user->userFacility)){  // there is field "speciality_id" in userFacility Table if its set to any integer value like 1,2,3 then is_doctor should set to 1 otherwise return zero if there is no speciality_id set
                foreach ($user->userFacility as $isDoctor){
                  
                }
            }
        $basicInfo =$user->userBasicInfo;
        $basicInfo['role']=$name;

            $basicInfo =$user->userBasicInfo;
            $basicInfo['is_doctor']=$doctor;

        $data[]=$basicInfo;
        }


    return response([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => "All Users",
        'total' => count($data),
        'data' => $data
    ], 200);
}
```

Currently where I am working is user has relationship with userFacility and there is field name "speciality_id" in userFacility table. I want to check if "speciality_id" is set then you can see I am creating is_doctor flag. It should set to 1 if there speciality_id and if no speciality_id it should set is_doctor flag to 0. I am trying something like below but did not get the result.

Comment: what you want output ?